# A careful solution to Problem 18.4 on page 111 of Munkres's Topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

The question is:

Given $y_0 \in Y $, show that the map $f:X\rightarrow X\times Y$ defined by $f(x) = x\times y_0$ is an imbedding.

Here is my attempt (following the definition of an imbedding given by Munkres on page 105):

(1) Is $f$ injective? Yes: Let $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1\times y_0 = x_2\times y_0 \implies x_1 = x_2$. Therefore $f$ is injective.

(2) Let $Z=f(X)$. Clearly, $Z = X\times \{y_0\}$. Consider $Z$ as a subspace of $X\times Y$.

(3) Define $f^\prime:X\rightarrow Z$, and it is bijective (it is injective (showed above) and surjective (for every $x\times y_0$ in $Z$, there exists an $x$ in $X$, so that $f^\prime(x) = x\times y_0$)).

(4) Is $f^\prime$ continuous? For every open set $V$ in $Z$, is $f^{\prime-1}(V)$ open in $X$? I show it as follows:
    Let $V$ be open in $Z$. Since $Z$ is a considered as a subspace of $X\times Y$, $V=W\cap Z$ where $W$ is open in $X\times Y$.
    Now, $W$ open in $X\times Y\implies W=\underset{\alpha\in J}\cup(B_\alpha\times C_\alpha)$
      where $B_\alpha$, $C_\alpha$ are basis elements of the basis that generates the topology on $X$ and $Y$, respectively.
    Therefore, $V=\underset{\alpha\in J}{\cup}(B_\alpha\times C_\alpha) \cap Z$
                $= \underset{\alpha\in J}{\cup}\big((B_\alpha\times C_\alpha) \cap (X\times\{y_o\})\big) $ as $Z=X\times\{y_0\}$ and using rules of Set Theory (page 11 of Munkres)
                $= \underset{\alpha\in J}{\cup}\big((B_\alpha\cap X) \times (C_\alpha\cap\{y_o\})\big) $
                $= \big(\underset{\beta\in K}{\cup}B_\beta\big)\times\{y_0\} $ where $K$ is the index set so that $y_0\in C_\beta$
                $= F\times\{y_0\} $ for some set $F$ open in $X$.
    Therefore, $F$ which is $f^{\prime-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.
This means that $f^\prime$ is continuous.

(5) Is $f^{\prime-1}$ continuous? Here $f^{\prime-1}:Z\rightarrow X$ is defined by $f^{\prime-1}(x\times y_0) = x$. For any open set $F$ in $X$, $f^{\prime}(F) = F\times{y_0}$ is open in $Z$ (as any open set in $Z$ can be written as a Cartesian product of an open set in $X$ times $\{y_0\}$).

Therefore, $f^\prime$ is a homeomorphism of $X$ with $Z=X\times\{y_0\}$. Hence, the map $f:X\rightarrow X\times Y$ is an imbedding.

What do you think? Is this a good solid proof?

Comment: @GEdgar Here is something I used from your answer to the previous question. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, but too complicated. Here is a suggestion.

1. If $\phi : A \to B$ is continuous and $\phi(A) \subset B' \subset B$, then the "codomain-restriction" $\phi' :  A \to B', \phi'(a) = \phi(a)$, is continuous. In fact, let $V' \subset B'$ be open in $B'$. Write $V ' = B' \cap V$ with an open $V \subset B$. Then $\phi^{-1}(V)$ is open in $A$. But $\phi^{-1}(V) = \{ a \in A \mid \phi(a) \in V \} = \{ a \in A \mid \phi(a) \in V' = B' \cap V \} = \{ a \in A \mid \phi'(a) \in V'\} = (\phi')^{-1}(V')$.
   Apply this to $f' : X \to Z$.
2. The projection $p : X \times Y$ is continuous. Therefore also the restriction $g =  p\mid_Z : Z \to X$ is continuous. By construction $g = (f')^{-1}$.